# Can Instant Apps handle deep links?

Tags: android, deep-linking

I want to develop a really simple Android prototype app.

The app needs to be compatible with Android Instant Apps.

1. The user will open the app without installing it (Instant Apps).
2. The user will use chrome to navigate to https://example.com/path (deep link).
3. The app will show a dialog with "Hello World" automatically because user navigated to https://example.com/path (deep link on AndroidManifest).

Is this possible with Instant Apps or just with installed apps?

Answer (score 0):

Yes: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/instant-app-links.html

It's the same setup as traditional apps with two key notes:

- All intent filters used as app links in your instant app must support both HTTP and HTTPS.
- Only one instant app can be declared for each website domain.

Comment: I can't use App Links, because they require verification. I really need use Deep Links + Instant Apps.